# Selenium WebDriver - element is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, nunit, automated-tests

*In relation to other questions regarding the inability to click elements which Selenium considers invisible, I am hoping this question carries a slightly different stance.*

I am using Selenium (.NET) along with NUnit for automated testing of a booking engine. At various stages of the test, Selenium is failing with an error surrounding element visibility. The element is however, visible and can be interacted with.

I have checked the computed styles from the element, all the way up the DOM tree in order to spot anything which Selenium might be seeing as a visibility issue, however I can see nothing.

At this point of exhaustion, I want to know if there is a way to configure Selenium to ignore these visibility checks entirely?

Comment: Without an example of what HTML and CSS styles being applied to it, I can only tell you what WebDriver uses to determine visibility: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#determining-visibility

Comment: @Arran - When the element is visible in the viewport, interaction works fine, but when the element has not been scrolled into view the element is not clickable, and throws an exception in WebDriver. I want to disable this...I don't see why it is necessary to have the browser window open, maximized and every element to be visible in order for interaction to work, hence, I want to disable visibility checking (if possible);

Comment: Selenium is based on real user interactions. If the browser window is small enough that the element you want to use is not visible, a real user wouldn't be able to use it and therefore Selenium isn't going to either.

Comment: Could there be a potential issue that the page doesn't render elements that are 'off screen'? As such, they don't exist in the DOM until scrolled into view? I seem to remember coming across such an issue before - using the JavascriptExecutor to scroll the window, and therefore 'force' rendering of those elements worked for me back then.

Comment: If you need to click on elements, obtain the values of the inputs, ... even when they are not visible, you can do it executing JQuery code with `executeScript("JQuery code")`. This is a workaround that may help you in many cases. If you want I can provide some examples.